# How to make a searchable Polygon map in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, polygon, spatial

I want to make a map of polygons in R.  I know all the vertices of the different polygons and know how to create polygons using:

```
library(sp)
Polygonoutline1 <- rbind(c(x1,y1),c(x2,y2),c(x3,y3))
Polygonshape1 <- Polygon(Polygonoutline1)
Polygonoutline2 <- rbind(c(x1,y1),c(x2,y2),c(x3,y3))
Polygonshape2 <- Polygon(Polygonoutline2)
Polys1 <- Polygons(list(Polygonshape1),"Shape 1")
Polys2 <- Polygons(list(Polygonshape2),"Shape 2")
map <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polys1,Polys2))
plot(map)
```

Now I want to be able to save (export) this plot and read it in to another R code algorithm where it can be searched i.e. I want to specify a point (xy coordinate) and want to know which polygon is at that point (i.e. "Shape 1" or "Shape 2".  How do I do this? In reality my map will have 6 or so polygons to search.

Comment: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/point.in.polygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define your Polygons e.g:

```
Kaplanturbineoutline <- rbind(c(0,0),c(60,0),c(950,15),c(170,80),c(10,80),c(0,20))
Kaplanturbinepolygon <- Polygon(Kaplanturbineoutline)

Francisturbineoutline <- rbind(c(4.5,12),c(125,12),c(910,15),c(910,80),c(100,700),c(6,700),c(0,55))
Francisturbinepolygon <- Polygon(Francisturbineoutline)

Crossflowturbineoutline <- rbind(c(0.3,3.5),c(10,3.5),c(10,10),c(0.3,100))
Crossflowturbinepolygon <- Polygon(Crossflowturbineoutline)
```

Then define Polygons (note the added 's'):

```
Kaplanpolys <- Polygons(list(Kaplanturbinepolygon),"Kaplan")
Francispolys <- Polygons(list(Francisturbinepolygon),"Francis")
Crossflowpolys <- Polygons(list(Crossflowturbinepolygon),"Crossflow")
```

Then define a Spatial Polygons map:

```
Turbinemap <- SpatialPolygons(list(Kaplanpolys,Francispolys,Crossflowpolys))
```

and define a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(c("Kaplan","Francis","Crossflow"),row.names=c("Kaplan","Francis","Crossflow"))
```

and then make a spatial polygons dataframe:

```
Turbinemapdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Turbinemap,df)
```

and this map can then be plotted:

```
spplot(Turbinemapdf,xlim=c(0,1000),ylim=c(0,1000),scales=list(draw=T),col=c("blue","orange","magenta","green","red"),fill=FALSE,colorkey=FALSE)
```

The map can then be searched using:

```
Turbineselection <<- over(Turbinemap,Turbinepoint)
```